# Upload tiff to mapbox gl js or mapbox.js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add a geotif image layer on map, I can do this in mapbox studio easily, Is there any way to do this using mapbox gl js library.
I added the geojson file using below code with mapbox gl js library:

```
      map.addSource("quakes", {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": "http://localhost:3000/Srikakulam.geojson"
      });
```

For tiff images I don't find any solution like this.

I have hundreds of tiff images to load dynamically based on weather and date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very uncommon to add georeferenced images like GeoTIFFs directly to a map. GeoTIFF is a relatively inefficient format, so the images will be very large, so requiring longer times to download and slower performance.

It's more common to process GeoTIFF into tiles: you can do so by uploading them to Mapbox, or by using a tool like TileMill, gdal2tiles, or MapTiler to generate tiles locally and then uploading those tiles to a server. Once you've generated tiles, you can include them in Mapbox GL JS, Mapbox.js, or any other client as a tile layer.

Comment: I'm a beginner, So can you please help me with example of converting geotiff into tiles in mapbox and how to include that to mapbox gl js as tile layer? @tmcw

Answer (score 0):

You can add `gif`, `png`, and `jpg` images to GL JS using the [`image` source type](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-image). [Here is an example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/).

Comment: I need it for georeferenced images(geotiff) .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert your tiff to gif/png/jpg and load as an image source type (as @lucas-wojciechowski suggested), couldn't you create a vector tile source in MapBox Studio Classic and load it into your MB-gl-js map as a [vector-source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/).

Note that vector tilesets, like most vector data formats, can also embed raster data, but that you lose vector functionality like over zooming, client-side rendering, and client-side data queries.

Comment: I have multiple tiff images of specified region, want to change images dynamically on the map.

Comment: upload all layers in one source, and change the visible layer dynamically via the [raster-opacity](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#paint-raster-opacity) paint property.  Or, if you have too many layers to load into one source, break them into many sources and load on demand via [`map.addSource`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#addSource) and `map.removeSource`.  The transition between sources probably isn't as nice as transition between styles w/i a single source, though.

Comment: Can you show some example of creating vector tile source and loading to mb-gl-js, I can provide the tiff image if you want.